# non rectangle image overlay

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I can't seem to figure this out. I have a bootstrap card which is 100% filled with an image. On top of the image I have some text which is made clearly visible by using a transparent rectangle overlay. I'd like the transparent rectangle overlay to be slanted so I get a similar effect to the cards on https://www.evensi.com home page.

My card HTML

```
<div class="card border-0" style="width:100%;">
<img class="card-img-top" src="IMAGE HERE" alt="Card image">
<div class="card-img-overlay">
</button>
<div class="bottom text-light">
SOME TEXT OVER IMAGE HERE
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Card styling

```
    .card {
        box-shadow: 1 3px 1px 1 rgba(1, 1, 3, 0.6);
        transition: 0.3s;
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 15px;
        padding: 3px;
    }

    .card:hover {
        box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }

    /* Card image dark filter */
    .card-img-top {
        width: 100%;
        height: 350px;
        object-fit: cover;
        /* photo brightness */
        filter: brightness(85%);
        border-radius: 15px;
        padding: 2px;
    }

    /* Align heading text to bottom of photo */
    .bottom {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        padding: 15px;
        bottom: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
        /* shaded filter overlay */
        background-color: rgba(12, 23, 23, 0.6);

        /* background-color: black; */
        border-top-left-radius: 0px;
        border-top-right-radius: 0px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    }
```

Comment: The one in the example is made with transform: rotate(); on an absolutely positioned element. Another way is to shape ::before pseudo element into a triangle of the same color of the background of the text container (http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/). And yet another way is to put a background-image of text container

Comment: Thanks, could you help with where I put the code because I'm unsure how to use ::before pseudo element ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 ways to have a slanted container:

- use transform: rotate(); on an element separate from your text container.
- use pseudo elements ::before or ::after
- use background-image of a .png file so that you can have transparency on your text container.

Pseudo elements ::before and ::after have to be attached to a desired element like a div, for example. They also have to have *content* property, otherwise they will not show at all.

```
div::before {
  content: "";
}
```

Their parent element is considered to be the element they are attached to, that would be *div* in this example. So you can use absolute positioning easily to position it according to your needs.

I made a fiddle with the card example.
https://jsfiddle.net/vbgrn98s/1/

You will have to play with border-width property to adjust its size to suit you.

Comment: that's great, thank you so much for taking the time to do this!